# difference between WebDriver Wait timeout and implicitlyWait timeout?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to know technical difference between WebDriver Wait timeout and implicitlyWait timeout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As said in [the documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits):

`Implicit Wait` sets internally a timeout that will be used for all consecutive `WebElement` searches. It will try lookup the element again and again for the specified amount of time before throwing an `NoSuchElementException` if the element could not have been found. It does only this and can't be forced into anything else - it waits for elements to show up.

`Explicit Wait`, or just `Wait` is a one-timer used by you for a particular search. It is more extendible in the means that you can set it up to wait for any condition you might like. Usually, you can use some of the prebuilt [`ExpectedConditions`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for elements to become clickable, visible, invisible, etc., or just write your own condition that suits your needs.

Comment: The text you've written here, while helpful, is quite different from the documentation you linked to (at least, in its current state). The docs don't say anything about Implicit Wait repeatedly looking for the element/condition/etc. (It does say that about Explicit Wait, of course.) Can you provide a reference, or an example, for Implicit wait that demonstrates this?

Comment: OK, it does say "implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to **poll the DOM**". Never mind. :-)

Comment: @LarsH I'm sorry but what exactly does "poll" mean here? And what does it usually mean in English?

Comment: @BruceSun, 'polling' in computers means repeatedly querying the same resource. It typically means a non-blocking query, so it's often a "busy wait", i.e. it keeps using the CPU while it's waiting for some condition to occur. In usual English, 'polling' means asking many people a question in order to report results from the whole group, as in Gallup polls. (Poll usually means an informal and non-binding question/answer, as opposed to a vote, which can have political force; but 'poll' can also be a synonym for taking a vote.)