# Firefox webdriver works too slow to find elements (selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using the selenium firefox WebDriver to retrieve many files that are download from the web with javascript.

The process works well normally but sometimes the firefox webdriver works too slow.

For example:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
String path = destDir;
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);        
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",path);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/plain;text/csv");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
//step 1
driver.navigate().to(url);
//step 2
WebElement element = driver.findElement(new By.ByXPath(...));
//step 3
element.click();                   
//step 4
element = driver.findElement(By.name("saveToFile"));
element.click();
```

Step 1 goes fast, it loads firefox and then navigates quickly to the URL (I can see it load and I can see how the webpage is loaded in the browser). But to finish step 2, sometimes, it takes too much time. I don't know why, because the page has loaded fast. Step 2 could take from 10 sec to 10 minutes!

I don't understand this behavior.  Why is this happening?  How can I change this?

Comment: It's better to use `driver.findElement(By.xpath(...))` instead of `driver.findElement(new By.ByXPath(...))`. How complicated is your XPath? XPath expressions are the strongest, but also the slowest - could you convert it to something different? Could you show us the expression? Maybe it's overly complicated and could be optimized. How long is your page? What is your Firefox and Selenium version?

Comment: Is not a question of xpath complex, one time the web page is load, the flow of execution is stuck in this step. I dont know why, i will try to use By.xpath... Thank you.

Comment: Also, put a `System.out.print("Ba dum - tss!");` between step 1 and step 2 to see whether step 1 is actually complete, please. Sometimes, the `get()` call blocks for a long time if a resource refuses to load... Do you have any Implicit wait set?

Comment: Sorry, what "implicit wait set" means?

Comment: For implicit wait check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244697/difference-between-webdriver-wait-timeout-and-implicitlywait-timeout

Comment: Thank you very much. I have discovered just now this link (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html). Ok now i am know what is "implicit wait".