# Not able to switch to pop-up window and find any elements in pop-up in Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, extjs, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have an application in which i tried clicking on a button and in return it will pop-up a window for filling a new user form. This is not really like a pop-up window, because it has some input fields as well as "save " and "cancel" button. It looks similar to pop-up window in facebook.

Here the code i tried with

```
Set beforePopup = driver.getWindowHandles();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/em/button")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Set afterPopup = driver.getWindowHandles();
    afterPopup.removeAll(beforePopup);
    if(afterPopup.size() == 1) {
          driver.switchTo().window((String)afterPopup.toArray()[0]);
        }

    //driver.switchTo().window("Add New User");
    //selenium.type("userDetailsBean.firstName","alan1");
    //WebElement btnStartQueryInside = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[14]/div/div/div/div/span"));
    //btnStartQueryInside.getText();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/input"));
    firstName.sendKeys("alan1");



    //driver.switchTo().alert();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[14]/div/div/div/div")).getText();
    //WebElement firstName=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/input"));
    //firstName.sendKeys("alan1");
    /*WebElement lastName=driver.findElement(By.id("userDetailsBean.lastName"));
    lastName.sendKeys("harper");
    WebElement emailadd=driver.findElement(By.id("userDetailsBean.userEmail"));
    emailadd.sendKeys("alan1@derik.com");
    WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.id("userDetailsBean.userName"));
    username.sendKeys("xalan1");
    WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.id("adminPassword"));
    password.sendKeys("Derik123");
    WebElement repassword=driver.findElement(By.id("adminPassword2"));
    repassword.sendKeys("Derik123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/em/button")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/
```

Please note that in code I commented some input field filling, because I thought first I will make it working just for 1st field. Please help me how to proceed.

the problem is after clicking the pop-up button, I'm not sure if the control switches to pop-up window or not. the gettitle after pop-up gives the main window title. and it is not able to find the first input field using the xpath or id.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: i edited the question adding the problem.

Comment: You do not need to switch to the "popup" for the message popup you have in your image. Directly interact with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `window` in Selenium means the actual browser window, not frames or just divs. Therefore, your logic is wrong, `getWindowHandles()` and `driver.switchTo().window("Add New User")` are not what you are after.

What you need is `driver.switchTo().frame()`.

```java
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // optional, use only if driver is already in an iframe

WebElement editUserForm = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='editUserForm']"));
// there are other overloads (by frame name, index, id) and locators can be used here.
driver.switchTo().frame(editUserForm);

// make sure your locator here is correct
WebElement lastName = driver.findElement(By.id("userDetailsBean.lastName")); // I doubt this is correct
// from your screenshot, I'd suggest By.cssSelector("[id*='userDetailsBean.lastName'] input")
lastName.sendKeys("harper");
```

Also just a kindly heads up, your code smells.

- Your implicitlyWait wait usage seems wrong, please read [the
  documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244697/difference-between-webdriver-wait-timeout-and-implicitlywait-timeout).
- Where did you get `selenium.type("userDetailsBean.firstName","alan1");`? Did you just copy the line from somewhere else? This looks like Selenium RC to me.
- Why `driver.switchTo().alert()`? Have you read [the documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html) on what's this for?
- Please don't use absolute xpath.
- Try use page object if you haven't done that in your real project. (It's fine if you just want to illustrate the problem here)

Comment: its working for me now.thanks.. I started working on webdriver coding 2 days back. Thanks for all your tips. It should help me.