# Selenium with phantomJS fails but is working in Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, xpath, phantomjs

I want to automate the download of my Google takeout data using Selenium with the PhantomJS webdriver. I developed the actions in the Selenium IDE Firefox add-on and converted the HTML output of the test case to JS using the npm package `selenium-html-js-converter`. My selectors are working perfectly in Mozilla Firefox 45.0.2 but if use the converted version it fails with the following message:

```
Error: Failure in Selenium command "click("//tbody[@data-id=drive]/tr/td/div/", "")": [elementByXPath("//tbody[@data-id=drive]/tr/td/div/")] Error response status: 32, , InvalidSelector - Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).
```

This is the part where I want to exclude certain Google apps from this takeout. I build all the selectors by hand since I don't want to rely on the classes and IDs of the elements since these are automatically generated by some build tool and could change at any time.

[I read in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101736/invalidselectorexception-using-css-selector-to-locate-data-attribute-notated) that quotes could be a problem but the evaluation still fails without quotes. I also tried to change my user agent in Firefox to the one which PhantomJS is using (`Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1`) just to make sure that the site output is the same but it's still working. However I don't know how to change the user agent string in Selenium.

My Selenium core code looks like the following (I omitted the automatically generated helper functions to keep it tidy):

```
"use strict";
/* jslint node: true */

var assert = require('assert');

var browser, element, currentCommand = '',
    options = {
        timeout: 30000,
        retries: 0,
        screenshotFolder: 'screenshots/test_minimal_takeout_mobile_html',
        baseUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/'
    };

module.exports = function testMinimalTakeoutMobileHtml(_browser, _options) {

    browser = _browser;
    var acceptNextAlert = true;
    getRuntimeOptions(_options);
    try {
        currentCommand = 'open("/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount#identifier", "")';
        browser.get(addBaseUrl("/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount#identifier"));

        currentCommand = 'type("id=Email", "email@gmail.com")';
        browser.elementById("Email").clear();
        browser.elementById("Email").sendKeys("email@gmail.com");

        currentCommand = 'click("id=next", "")';
        browser.elementById("next").click();

        currentCommand = 'uncheck("id=PersistentCookie", "")';
        if (browser.elementById("PersistentCookie").isSelected()) {
            browser.elementById("PersistentCookie").click();
        };

        currentCommand = 'type("id=Passwd", "password")';
        browser.elementById("Passwd").clear();
        browser.elementById("Passwd").sendKeys("password");

        currentCommand = 'clickAndWait("id=signIn", "")';
        doAndWait(function() {
            browser.elementById("signIn").click();
        });

        currentCommand = 'open("https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout", "")';
        browser.get(addBaseUrl("https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout"));

        currentCommand = 'click("//tbody[@data-id=\'drive\']/tr/td/div/", "")';
        //<<< It fails here >>>
        browser.elementByXPath("//tbody[@data-id=\'drive\']/tr/td/div/").click();

        currentCommand = 'click("//tbody[@data-id=\'chat\']/tr/td/div/", "")';
        browser.elementByXPath("//tbody[@data-id=\'chat\']/tr/td/div/").click();

        currentCommand = 'click("//tbody[@data-id=\'gmail\']/tr/td/div/", "")';
        browser.elementByXPath("//tbody[@data-id=\'gmail\']/tr/td/div/").click();

        currentCommand = 'click("//div[@data-state=\'1\']/div[2]/div[2]/div", "")';
        browser.elementByXPath("//div[@data-state=\'1\']/div[2]/div[2]/div").click();

        currentCommand = 'mouseDown("//div[@data-param=\'destination\']/div[2]/div[@role=\'presentation\']/div[2]", "")';
        browser.elementByXPath("//div[@data-param=\'destination\']/div[2]/div[@role=\'presentation\']/div[2]").mouseDown();

        currentCommand = 'mouseUp("//div[@data-param=\'destination\']/div[2]/div[@role=\'presentation\']/div[2]", "")';
        browser.elementByXPath("//div[@data-param=\'destination\']/div[2]/div[@role=\'presentation\']/div[2]").mouseUp();

        currentCommand = 'click("//div[@data-param=\'destination\']/div[2]/div[3]/div[@data-value=\'DRIVE\']", "")';
        browser.elementByXPath("//div[@data-param=\'destination\']/div[2]/div[3]/div[@data-value=\'DRIVE\']").click();

        currentCommand = 'click("//div[@data-state=\'2\']/div[2]/div[2]/div", "")';
        browser.elementByXPath("//div[@data-state=2]/div[2]/div[2]/div").click();

    } catch (e) {
        var failedScreenShot = options.screenshotFolder + '/Exception@' + currentCommand.replace(/\(.+/, '') + '.png';
        try {
            createFolderPath(options.screenshotFolder);
            browser.saveScreenshot(failedScreenShot);
        } catch (e) {
            e.message = 'Failure in Selenium command "' + currentCommand + '": ' + e.message + ' (Could not save screenshot after failure occured)';
            throw e;
        }
        e.message = 'Failure in Selenium command "' + currentCommand + '": ' + e.message + ' (Screenshot was saved to ' + failedScreenShot + ')';
        throw e;
    }

};
```

The screenshot which is taken when the test fails shows me the correct page.

I'm using the latest stable releases of NodeJS(5.10.1), PhantomJS (2.1.1) and Selenium (2.53.1).

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote each attribute value to make the XPath valide:

```
browser.elementByXPath("//tbody[@data-id='drive']/tr/td/div/").click();
```

Comment: The attribute values with quotes where the auto-generated code and my first attempt which failed. But I'll edit my answer to show the correct XPath.

Comment: The XPath is still incorrect, you need to remove the escape in front of the quote.