# How to click the element if the value of the id attribute starts with numbers using Selenium in IE11

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I checked the existing answers and it looks like there is no answered question regarding this.

Here it is: selenium 32 bit driver, IE 11, windows 10 64bit.
I need to find the elements with the unique static `id = 0idMenuTitle` or `1idMenuTitle`

HTML code

SPAN onmouseover="if(this.style.backgroundColor !=BgColorON)this.style.backgroundColor = BgColorOVER;" onmouseout="if(this.style.backgroundColor !=BgColorON)this.style.backgroundColor = BgColorOFF;" id=1idMenuTitle class=clsMenuTitle style="MAX-WIDTH: none; MIN-WIDTH: auto; MIN-HEIGHT: auto; MAX-HEIGHT: none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cccc" minmax_bound="true" width="100%">menu1

I'm using the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("0idMenuTitle")).click();
```

and have the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #\31 idMenuTitle
```

I'm trying to find with the partial id

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id*=MenuTitle]")).click();
```

but got

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not displayed
```

I tried with Xpath as well, the same errors.
There is no issue if I'm using FF or GC but I must use IE11, no choice.
There is no problem to find the elements with id that does not start with numbers...

Any idea please?

### Update

I'm trying to find the element by id starting with 0, but selenium shows the error regarding css selector (?) and the id #\31 (???)

Comment: A suggestion from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11284187/384049 is to verify that your browser can find the element directly (without Selenium), e.g. With a number as the first character of an id: `document.querySelector("#2forTandT4two")` which gives me an error in Chromium instead of returning the element or `null`.  I don't know if it's a recent change that you can't use an id starting with a number for a css selector.  I hat thought this worked...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `Element is not displayed` because item is not visible on the page while interacting.Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `elementToBeClickable`()

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[id*='MenuTitle']"))).click();
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: no, does not help. I got this:
TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: [id*='1idMenuTitle'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Can you post the HTML of that element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a couple of things as follows:

- A [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) with the value of *id* attribute as *0idMenuTitle* or *1idMenuTitle* is **not** a static id, it's dynamic id, i.e. partial value is assigned when the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) gets completely loaded. Hence when you use `By.id("0idMenuTitle")` you face *NoSuchElementException*.
- But when you use `[id*=MenuTitle]` you are seeing *ElementNotInteractableException* as the *locator strategy* finds some other element which is not **displayed** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

---

### Solution

To invoke click on the desired element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *id*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("0idMenuTitle"))).click();
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#0idMenuTitle"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='0idMenuTitle']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: sorry, does not work, shows the error: TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='1idMenuTitle'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval), the same for id and css selector...